# I am trying to set bottom of element but its value is coming up NaN

Tags: javascript

```
function CheckavailOnload()
{
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box-collateral box-related');
  var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');
  var x;
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  {
    if (getComputedStyle(elems[i]).visibility == 'visible') 
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < av.length; j++)
      {
        av[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
        if(elems[i].offsetTop < 0)
        {
          var x = (elems[i].offsetHeight + (elems[i]).offsetTop).toString() + "px";
          alert(x);
        }
        for(m = 0;m < av.length; m++)
        {
          av[m].style.Bottom = (-x);
          return;
        }
       }
     }
   }
   for (var k = 0; k < av.length; k++)
   {
     av[k].style.visibility = 'hidden';
   }
   var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart');
   for(var l = 0; l < divs.length; l++)
   { 
     divs[l].style.marginTop = (-500).toString() + "px";
     divs[l].style.marginLeft = (-20).toString() + "px";
   }
}
window.onload = CheckavailOnload;
```

here i am trying to move a paragraph tag have baground image depending upon the div offsetTop and Offset height div also have bacground image i am moving para tag just below the div but addition of offsetHeight and offsetTop is coming NAN please anyone can help me

Comment: Can you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: yes-David http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/35/

Comment: So, what part of the jsFiddle's behavior do you not like?

Comment: my site address http://efg.gostorego.com/occasion/birthday/make-a-wish.html i am trying to move that upward image as a closing for box choose Extra to make it more spacial please check first this you'll understand

Comment: how we can move a element below the other element dynamically at any position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared `var x;` at the beginning of your script. Then later you're checking:

```
if(elems[i].offsetTop < 0) {
    var x = (elems[i]...); // var is not recommended to be here, x has been already declared once
}
```

If `elems[i].offsetTop` happens to be `>= 0`, `x` will be `undefined` in this line:

```
av[m].style.Bottom = (-x); // Notice a typo here: should be av[m].style.bottom
```

This last expression gives you `NaN`. To avoid this, you need to either assign a default value to `x` in the beginning of the script, or add an `else` statement after the `if` wherein some numeric value is assigned to `x`.

Also `return` in the `for...m`-loop seems to break your code, the loop will never finish the job and the rest of the code will be never executed.

Using `(-500).toString() + "px";` feels complex, why not just use `"-500px";`?

Comment: var x;
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  {
    if (getComputedStyle(elems[i]).visibility == 'visible') 
    {
      for (var j = 0; j < av.length; j++)
      {
        av[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
        if(elems[i].offsetTop >= 0)
        {
          x = (elems[i].offsetHeight + elems[i].offsetTop).toString() + "px";
          alert(x);
        }
        for(m = 0;m < av.length; m++)
        {
          av[m].style.bottom = (-x);
        }
       }
     }
     return;
   }

Comment: Teemu@please just check this still its not working http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/65/ i want to move availibility tag dynamically num of elements in div can be variable plus div position can be littel bit up or down as necessary and margin of a div should not be added

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your comment at all :-(. However, your fiddle misses the closing tag for `.box-collateral`. Also when using a variable and a string together, you'll need to concatenate the values with `+` (`-x + 'px'`), only literal numeric values can be combined (like `"-500px"`).

Comment: ok please can you check http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/69/ i wana to move availablity tag below div

Comment: actually i moved p tag in CSS using .product-view .product-shop .availability{bottom:-610px} but now i want to move dynamically and that also using class name so how i can writte for this<div class="product-main-info">
    <p class="availability in-stock">Availability</p>
</div>

Comment: var av = document.getElementsByClassName('availability in-stock');

Comment: i changes as you said but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/7EGSm/79/ i want to move only tag p after the div tag with class name <div class="box-collateral box-related">

Comment: @geetabattin Finally got it work... Please see http://jsfiddle.net/CheBa/2/ , that's what I've understood you're needing. Unfortenately the code doesn't work in FF, but IE, Chrome and Opera seems to execute it fine. I'll do some research to get it work in FF too, if this was really the code you needed.

Comment: actually i want availability tag below the div and i want to calculate the div position from top +div height and both are variable and aft that taking that addition i want to move tag p or availablity below the the div.

Comment: Actually this discussion has really exeeded the limits set by your original question, once again... : ). However, it's not possible to get the `p` out of the `div .product-main-info` without breaking the whole layout of the page. It just can't be done with some tricks with margins... Please check http://jsfiddle.net/CheBa/4/ , if the `p` is now in the correct place (this fiddle works for almost any browser).